# C#: Read Console Input Text After Space

Tags: c#, console-application

I want my C# program to be able to read any text (Console.ReadLine) after a space character in console input efficiently. For example, if the user types in `display stack_overflow_rocks!`, the program should print out stack_overflow_rocks! in the console (Console.WriteLine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string input = "display stack_overflow_rocks!";
string[] stringSeparator = new string[] {" "};
var result = source.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

`result[1]` would be `stack_overflow_rocks!`

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I later found your answer more useful (not just answers question, goes beyond). Your post was re-accepted!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(s.IndexOf(" ") + 1, s.Length - 1 - s.IndexOf(" ")));
```

PS - Code is unit tested.

Comment: Seems more concise than the first answer, so I transferred the "accepted" status